# Oracle Time Comparison to sysdate issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having problem to getting data on filtering on exact date.
when I am running following query, I am getting result

```
select * from table d
where D.TIME_STAMP >=  SYSDATE -39
```

Return 36789 Rows

When I am trying to get data for one day, it runs 0 rows. I already check table I have the data for specifically require a date, but my query does not return any row.
when I am running following query

```
select * from table d
where D.TIME_STAMP =  SYSDATE -39
```

Return 0 Rows.

I m using Oracle 11g, and my table already has field name table_stamp with require date data. 
Datatype of TIME_STAMP NOT NULL DATE

Comment: time_stamp data type = TIME_STAMP NOT NULL DATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `TIME_STAMP` column has no time component (i.e. the time component is `00:00:00`) then you can do the comparison using:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table d
WHERE  D.TIME_STAMP =  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 39;
```

If the column has a time component and you are trying to get all rows that were 39 days ago then you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table d
WHERE  TRUNC( D.TIME_STAMP ) =  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 39;
```

However, that will then mean that you cannot use an index on the `TIME_STAMP` column (but could use a function-based index on `TRUNC( TIME_STAMP )`).

That can be solved by using:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table d
WHERE  D.TIME_STAMP >=  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 39
AND    D.TIME_STAMP <   TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 38;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use TRUNC() to remove the time from the date:

```
select * from table d
where trunc(D.TIME_STAMP) =  trunc(SYSDATE -39)
```

I don't know what format you keep in TIME_STAMP, but even if it trunced , sysdate produce a date with a time as to what time your computer is set to.

**EDIT** If you dont want to use trunc for index, use this:

```
select * from table d
where D.TIME_STAMP >=  trunc(SYSDATE -39) 
  AND D.TIME_STAMP < trunc(SYSDATE -38)
```

Comment: I already tried with trunc... and my table is quite big so trunc is not a option  because trunc ignore the index and i don't want to run my query without indexing.. Currently i have indexing on time_stamp column.

Comment: @AnisNoorAli I've add a solution without trunc

Comment: Alternate way is better. But i got the solution by checking  select * from table d
where to_date(D.TIME_STAMP) >=  to_date(SYSDATE -39)